# What does "having עונות ידועים" mean?

Tags: words, mishnah-berurah

What does "having עונות ידועים" mean in the language of the Mishnah Berurah? You can see it at the bottom of the right side of this page : http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_digest/Chelek_6/1524_Siman_571_Seif_1-3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It means "known sins". The article is saying that if the talmud chacham knows that he has sinned, then he must fast (to help atone for his sins).